# Run jQuery after all content on page is loaded in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a directive where I am including some jQuery like this:

```
app.directive('openjs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $('.active').parents('.fullSectionAccordion').fadeIn('fast');
                $('.active').parents('.accordionSection').fadeIn('fast');
            });

        }  // end jQuery
    };
});
```

The `.active` class is being generated by ng-class in Angular so jQuery isn't picking it up, how do I wait until all of the ng-classes have been set to fire the jQuery?

Comment: shouldn't need jQuery at all for this, use `ng-show` on parent along with css animations. Read up on how `ngAnimate` works

Comment: Usually I would but in this particular case ng-show doesn't work

Comment: probably need to use `$timeout`. Need to see more code. Don't understand why `ng-show` wouldn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Look this: (angular.element)[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element]

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

You don't need jQuery in AngularJS (mostly cases).

You can access element throught 2nd parameter of `link` function. It is jQuery element. AngularJS has some methods to work with element. Documentation is avaiable by link above.

Comment: I switched all of the `$` with `angular.element` it doesn't make any difference, the angular version of jQuery still fires before the ng-classes are loaded so it can't select them.